# How to enter text in a text-input inside an atomic block

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have an atomic block rendered in the following manner:

```
const blockRendererFn = (block) => {
    if (block.getType() === 'atomic') {
      return {
        component: (props) => (
          <AtomicBlockRenderer {...{
            ...props,
            getEditorState: () => editorState,
            setEditorState: (editorState) => dispatchSetEditorState(editorState),
            editorEl
          }}/>
        ),
        editable: true
      }; 
    }

    return null;
  };

const AtomicBlockRenderer = (props) => {
  const { contentState, block } = props;
  const entity = contentState.getEntity(block.getEntityAt(0));
  const type = entity.getType();

  switch (type) { 
    case 'video': return <VideoInput {...{...props, entity}} />;
    default: return null;
  }
};


import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export const VideoInput = (props) => {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div
      className="video-input"
    >
      <input
        ref={inputEl}
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="paste youtube or vimeo url"
      />
    </div>
  );  
};
```

I am not able to focus on the `input` element inside `VideoInput`. Even if I hook up focus somehow using `ref`, the editor crashes as my content-state becomes malformed. How can I set up the input element to receive URLs from users?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-hypatia-61g3x

Comment: Care to provide a workable sandbox so that its easier for us to help in with your problem ?

Comment: @dev_junwen added sandbox at the end of question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch the editor to read only mode when the user tries to interact with the input field. You can do that by adding an `onFocus` handler to the input field that sets the editor to read only.

To demonstrate that this is what you need, try the following steps:
 * Add a video element
 * Open the React debugger and flip the `readOnly` flag to `true` on the `DraftEditor` component
 * Try to type something in the input field

See https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor#readonly for further reference.